# Unable to locate element - Selenium Javascript testing

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a javascript  to be tested with selenium.
But I am facing the issue

> unable to locate a specific element

to perform click operation. Below is snippet of my JS and I want click on Shipping. Tried all locators like findelement by id,linktext,cssselector etc but nothing works.

```
<ul
className="navbar-nav bg-black sidebar sidebar-dark accordion"
id="accordionSidebar"
>
<Link
className="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
to="/ONE"
>
<div className="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">
<img src={logo} width={220} height={60}/>
</div>
</Link>

<hr className="sidebar-divider my-0" />

<li className={`nav-item ${props.selectedTab === 'ONE' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
<Link className="nav-link" to="/ONE">
<i className="fas fa-fw fa-th" />
<span>ONE</span>
</Link>
</li>

<li className={`nav-item ${props.selectedTab === 'TWO' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
<Link className="nav-link" to="/TWO">
<i className="fas fa-fw fa-truck" />
<span>TWO</span>
</Link>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add the most recent code you tried to use to navigate to the page and locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what the code would be since you didn't provide your current selenium test and I don't see a link for shipping, but you could try something like this

```js
// Targeting a button element for this example
When('I click {string} button', async function(buttonText) {
  const driver: webdriver.WebDriver = this.driver;

  const buttonElement = await driver.findElement(
    webdriver.By.xpath(`//button[contains(.,'${buttonText}')]`),
  );

  await buttonElement.sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER);
});
```